# Read, change, then write csv data in python

Tags: python, csv

How can I output the data I've formatted to a csv file? I believe it's possible to write each line as I clean them but I'm not sure how.  The basic goal I'm trying to achieve is to iterate through all rows of the csv and change only the items in the rows that meet the criteria of the for loop. Then output all the changed and unchanged rows back out to another csv.

```
import csv
import sys
import re

fileToClean = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
readerObj = csv.reader(fileToClean)

for row in readerObj:
  for item in row:
    if " TB" in item:
      newitem = item.replace(" TB","")
      result = re.sub('[^0-9]','',newitem)
      result = float(newitem) * 1024
      result = round(result, 2)
    elif " MB" in item:
      newitem =  item.replace(" MB", "")
      result = re.sub('[^0-9]','',newitem)
      result = float(result) / 1000
      result = round(result, 2)
    elif " GB" in item:
      newitem = item.replace(" GB", "")
      result = re.sub('[^0-9]','',newitem)
      result = float(result)
      result = round(result, 2)
```

Comment: To write a csv file, simply write each line as a comma separated string. You don't need any extra package. Open a file in append mode, and append each line (row) when you have processed them.

Comment: @warmoverflow I'm not sure how to do that, can you explain?

Comment: before first `for` open file to write . `with open('target_file', 'w') as tf :` . Then repeat `tf.write(result)` inside each if block.

Comment: @minatverma won't that only write the results of the changed lines?

Comment: add an extra `else` at last to write non matched line .

Comment: @minatverma ok I tried that, target file comes out emtpy. Can you show me what you mean, maybe I made a mistake?

Comment: can you provide some input data and desired output . I might write the code . Its not very clear your intent here .Please edit your question with the sample input and output .

Comment: @minatverma sure, im not sure how to properly post it though.

Comment: edit your question . post the data at the bottom of the question . this will save time for others answer writers who would just try to guess what you are trying to achieve here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newfile = open("test.csv", "w")
for row in readerObj:
  newrow = []
  for item in row:
    if " TB" in item:
      item = item.replace(" TB", "")
      item = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', item)
      item = float(item) * 1024
      item = round(item, 2)
    elif " MB" in item:
      item =  item.replace(" MB", "")
      item = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', item)
      item = float(item) / 1000
      item = round(item, 2)
    elif " GB" in item:
      item = item.replace(" GB", "")
      item = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', item)
      item = float(item)
      item = round(item, 2)
    newrow.append(str(item))
  newfile.write(','.join(newrow) + '\n')
newfile.close()
fileToClean.close()
```

Comment: Also, as a good practice, always remember to either close the file manually, or use `with open(file, 'w') as f:`

Comment: This produces an empty output file.

Comment: I have tested my code and it works. Please post a sample of your input data so I can test again.

Comment: My mistake, the read file had been cleared prior to any formatting. You solution works, thank you very much!

Comment: how would I iterate over the reader object again prior to writing to the new file?

Comment: In order to make more formatting changes, changes that would be outside the scope of the for loop. Let's say I wrapped the for loop inside a function, then I could create another function and make changes in addition to the ones made in the code above.

Comment: Currently it's writing a new line when it reads a line. To be able to iterate again before writing, you need to store all new lines in a big list, and then write them all together.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to accomplish what you are trying to do is to read your file as a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list), make your changes, and then write the list to a new file:

```
import csv
import sys
import re

fileToClean = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
readerObj = list(csv.reader(fileToClean))

# ...iterate through readerObj, changing whatever items you want...

with open("newFile", "w") as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for line in readerObj:
        wr.writerow(line)
```

Comment: that files comes out empty

Comment: if you are able to include a snippet of your input file in your question, I may be able to provide additional help.